# How To Detect If Another Process Reading My Application's Memory

Tags: memory, anti-cheat

Is it possible to detect if another process reading the memory of my application? If so, can you give me any examples on how to accomplish this? (examples in C++ would be great)

Thank You

Comment: Is not possible. It is private memory. Only your app may access to requested memory

Comment: @Valijon, that is absolutely not true, system APIs allow the reading and writing of memory in other processes (e.g. `WriteProcessMemory` on windows).

Answer (score 2):

To detect a process that opens a handle to your process and calls ReadProcessMemory you must either, hook OpenProcess & ReadProcessMemory in every process or have a kernel mode driver that intercepts these calls.

Detecting ReadProcessMemory solely from inside the target process is usermode is not possible to my knowledge.  I have seen this question come up many times and have never seen an acceptable answer.